# How use "ejabber_sm" in my ejabber module?

Tags: module, erlang, ejabberd

I try write ejabber module. I try to use ejabber_sm, but I can't find examples.
I try:

```
-module(mod_auto_muc).

-behavior(gen_mod).

-include("ejabberd.hrl").
-include("logger.hrl").

-export([start/2, stop/1, on_user_available/1]).

start(Host, _Opts) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("mod_auto_muc starting on Host: ~p", [Host]),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(user_available_hook, Host, ?MODULE, on_user_available, 50),
    ok.

stop(Host) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("mod_auto_muc stopping on Host: ~p", [Host]),
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(user_available_hook, Host, ?MODULE, on_user_available, 50),
    ok.

on_user_available(Jid) ->
    ConnectedUsers = ejabber_sm:connected_users(),
    ?INFO_MSG("Connected users ~p", [ConnectedUsers]),
    ok.
```

After run I getting:

> [error] {undef,[{ejabber_sm,get_user_resources,[<<"atterratio">>,<<"localhost">>],[]}

I think that need to connect additional modules but do not know what.
Who can tell in this case. Or better yet a link to examples of writing different modules for ejabberd. Besides [this](http://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is called `ejabberd` with a `d` at the end, and so are the modules: it should be `ejabberd_sm`, not `ejabber_sm`.